# Only execute javascript if css is display:block - issue with resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website with two banners- one for mobile and one for desktop. In order to have both banners functioning I had to write an if statement that a past of the dsktop javascript is only executed if the desktop banneris set to display:block in the css. 
This works fine, but the only problem is when the user resizes the window the if statement doesn't get executed- they have to reload the page to do that.

this is the code :

```
var wait = setInterval(function () {
 if (!$(currentBanner, loading).is(":animated")) {
  clearInterval(wait);
  loading.stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
 if ($('#banner').css('display') == 'block'){
  setTimeout(function() {
  bannerInit();
  }, 800);
  startInterval();
 if (initialLoad) {
  initialLoad = false;
  next.slideDown();
  previous.slideDown();
 }
 }
});
}
```

Does anybody know how I can trigger the if statement not only on page load but also on resizing of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
// on document ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
  /* your function/code here */
});

// on page load, all elements finished e.g images etc
$(window).load(function() {
 /* your function/code here */
});

// on page resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){ 
 /* your function/code here */
};
```

Or vanilla JS:

```
// page load
window.onload = function() {
  /* your function/code here */
};

// resize    
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunctionOnResize);
```

Comment: Thanks that works, only issue is that I need the function executed on resize and pageload so when I add the resize it only does it once the window is resized, not when the page is loaded